# React Router - Is there an 'easier' way to route to a new path besides using Context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Is there an easier or perhaps more recent way to be able to, for instance, click on a button and onClick of that button, reroute to a new path?

....BESIDES using the context method on the component?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways:

1.[**withRouter**](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options) - HoC from react-router (higher-order component) that wraps another component to provide **props.router**

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {
   ...
    onClickButton(){
      this.props.router.push('/path')
    }
   ...
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

2.**History singleton** (hashHistory / browserHistory)

```
import { hashHistory} from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {
   ...
    onClickButton(){
      hashHistory.push('/path')
    }
   ...
}
```

3.Also you can **get history** from props in **component, wich is passed to route**

```
....
<Route path="/" component={App} />
```

then in Component

```
class App extends Component {
   ...
    onClickButton(){
      this.props.history.push('/path')
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I'm liking number 3. So in the third example, basically the App component is now inheriting a property called history because App is being called by Route? That's cool. Also...

Comment: Also... Does this mean that you can do history.push(*ANY PATH THAT IS USING ROUTER*)?? Thanks.